# Why aren't my if else codes working?

Tags: c++

I am making a simple random number guesser game (example below), and it works perfectly until your guess is higher than the number. when it happens, it prints: "My number is lower than thatMy number is higher than that" When it is just supposed to print "My number is lower than that". Also, when you guess the right answer, it prints "My number is higher than that"

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    int highnum;
    int guess;
    srand(time(0));
    std::cout << "Pick a number greater than 2";
    std::cin >> highnum;
    int randynumeber = (rand () % highnum) + 1;
    std::cout << "I have picked a random number between 1 and " << highnum << " which you need to try and guess";
    int guesses = 0;
    int stop = 0;

    while (guess != randynumeber)  
        {
            if (stop == 0)
                {
                    sleep(0.1);
                    stop = 1;
                    std::cout << std::endl << "Guess a number";
                    std::cin >> guess;
                    if(guess>randynumeber)
                        std::cout << "My number is lower than that";
                    else if(guess<randynumeber)
                        std::cout << "My number is higher than that";
                    stop = 0;  
                }    
        }
    std::cout << std::endl << "guesses = " << guesses; 
    std::cout << "You win!";  
}
```

Comment: Please post the code in your question.

Comment: Don't post links of code. Links die.

Comment: `std::cout << "My number is higher than that";` will always print since it's under no condition (notice the `;` & `else` when it should be `else if` or simply `else` with no args). Also, what do you expect `stop` to do? And you're not incrementing guesses.

Comment: yr code will never end because you always end up setting stop = 0

Comment: Prefer to use `bool` and `true` and `false` rather than integers of 1 and 0.

Comment: how can I put the code in my question? I clicked the code button, and it said to put 4 spaces, but it still didn't work

Comment: @MrSam123 You paste the code, mark it with the mouse, and click the code button or type Ctl-k.

Answer (score 0):

You are not testing the condition on the else statement. You need to test it otherwise it simply executes `( guess < randynumeber);`  - which gives a logic answer and then executes the next piece of code which is the next `cout` statement.

Comment: I just changed my code a bit, but I dont get what you are saying, how do I test it?

Comment: Is the code in the question different from what you saw when you posted this answer? I just copied it from the offsite link.

Comment: yes, it looks like it has been changed - the answer above it also refers to a missing test on the else condition